# Making text to image

Tags: javascript, html

What i am trying to do is making Y[0] become the image and not text. Right now it's just just the link as plain text and not an image.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeContent(){
    var x=document.getElementById('myTable').rows
    var y=x[0].cells
    y[0].innerHTML = "http://www.handicappedpets.com/wizards/img/wwmeasure2B.jpg"
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr>
<td>d</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>d</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
</table>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="changeContent()" value="Change content">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So make it an images element and set the url as `src` attribute?

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve? This implementation is pretty rigid - there's likely a better approach to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just setting the html of the cell to some text which happens to be a url. You need to create an img tag inside the cell:

```
y[0].innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.handicappedpets.com/wizards/img/wwmeasure2B.jpg" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
y[0].innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.handicappedpets.com/wizards/img/wwmeasure2B.jpg" alt="Remove Criteria" />'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
y[0].innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.handicappedpets.com/wizards/img/wwmeasure2B.jpg">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the image source in the  tag, like this

```
y[0].innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.handicappedpets.com/wizards/img/wwmeasure2B.jpg'/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image dynamically with javascript and append it to the cell.

```
window.changeContent = function () {
    var x = document.getElementById('myTable').rows,
        cell = x[0].cells[0],
        img = document.createElement('img');

    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.handicappedpets.com/wizards/img/wwmeasure2B.jpg');

    cell.innerHTML = '';
    cell.appendChild(img);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7KZu/

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. What you can do is put that URL inside an  tag and insert that, or create a new Image() object, set the src property of it and insert it into the DOM.

Comment: No, you can't make a Javascript variable point to an image. What Rhumborl suggested was putting that URL into an <img> tag (which is incidentally what I suggested) and you've downvoted my answer for it. Thanks.